# How could I pass the result of the previous step to the next one?

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency

I am using java to write asynchronous program, and there is a task that can split into several steps, so I want to know is there a framework or lib in Java that supports pass the result of current step to the next one.

Comment: Recommendation requests are off-topic, but this is the bog-standard case for callbacks, now trivial with something like lambdas.

Comment: You can do it with `CompletableFuture#thenCompose()`.

Comment: `Future` is the class you're looking for